# Break Statement Leads To 'SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Tags: python, function, if-statement, break

This to me seem to be a simple line of code yet I receive a "SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop" error and I can't seem to figure out why. I'm still fairly new to coding; I apologize if the solution is very obvious.

```
def correct():
          print('What Is Your Greatest Desire')
          ans2 = input()
          return '\n' + ans2 + ' is what you shall receive'
          if 4 > 2:
            break
```

Comment: What are you hoping to happen on `break` you are not in a loop in the scope of the break. And you will never actually get to it because you `return` before `if 4 > 2:`.

Comment: There's no loop there. I'm not sure what your question actually is.

Comment: Your error is indicating that you are using a break but not in a loop. Your break is in a conditional if statement, not a loop.

Comment: You might work through a tutorial on the `break` statement to learn how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `break` which will exit you out of whatever top level `for:` or `while:` loop you are in. However, you are not using loops at all in this code. I imagine you are looking to leave your function and return to your main script, but you have already returned prior to this segment. This is what I **think** you are looking for:

```
def correct():
    user_input = input("What is your desire")
    try:
        number = int(user_input)
        if number > 2:
            return None
        else:
            return '\n' + number + ' is what you shall receive'
    except:
        print("You need to input a number")
```

Comment: if this solved your problem you should accept it as the answer